# Powershell Using a CSV list to check a folder for missing files

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, compare, directory

I'm kind of new to scripting, forgive me for any obvious answers here.

Basically, I have a large list of music files stored in a folder that I update every month. I created a smaller folder for testing purposes:

[image: music folder]

I have a CSV list of all the files that should be in the folder:

[image: CSV File with missing entry]

I'm trying to create a Powershell script that:

- Takes the CSV column "Audio File Path" names and compares it with the file names in the folder "Music"
- Checks if there are any missing files in either the CSV list or the Music folder
- Output the names of the missing files

My testing script so far (Edited):

```
$folder = 'C:/Users/Me/Documents'
$myFolder = Get-ChildItem '/Users/Me/Documents/Music' 
$myCSV = Import-Csv -Path 'Documents/AudioMissing.csv'| % {$_.'Audio File Path' -replace "\\", ""}

$compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $myCSV -DifferenceObject $myFolder

foreach($y in $compare){
    if($y.SideIndicator -eq "=>"){
     write-output "$($y.InputObject) Is present in the Music folder but not in the CSV."
    }
    if($y.SideIndicator -eq "<="){
     write-output "$($y.InputObject) Is present in the CSV but not in Music folder."
    }
 }
```

Except when I run the script, it returns all the files from the list and the folder and also says some are missing even though they are the same file name.

Output looks like this (Edited):

```
9913SA_FIle1.wav Is present in the Music folder but not in the CSV.
9914SA_File2.wav Is present in the Music folder but not in the CSV.
9915SA_File3.wav Is present in the Music folder but not in the CSV.
9916SA_File4.wav Is present in the Music folder but not in the CSV.
9917SA_File5.wav Is present in the Music folder but not in the CSV.
9913SA_FIle1.wav Is present in the CSV but not in Music folder.
9914SA_File2.wav Is present in the CSV but not in Music folder.
9915SA_File3.wav Is present in the CSV but not in Music folder.
9916SA_File4.wav Is present in the CSV but not in Music folder.
```

I want the script to output just the missing files like this:

```
 9917SA_File5.wav Is present in the Music folder but not in the CSV.
```

Is this possible to do?

---

### EDIT:

Turns out my CSV file actually had hidden spaces at the end of each "Audio File Path" entry causing it to read like a different name.

New code

```
$myFolder = Get-ChildItem '/Users/Me/Documents/Music' | % {$_.Name}
$myCSV = Import-Csv -Path '/Users/Me/Documents/AudioMissing.csv' | % {$_.'Audio File Path' -replace "\\", ""}
$compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $myCSV -DifferenceObject $myFolder -includeequal

Write-Output "`n_____FOLDER_____`n"
$myFolder

Write-Output "`n_____CSV_____`n"
$myCSV

Write-Output "`n_____COMPARE_____`n"
$compare

Write-Output "`n_____Formatted Results____`n"
foreach($y in $compare){
    if($y.SideIndicator -eq "=>"){
     write-output "$($y.InputObject) Is present in the Music folder but not in the CSV."
    }
    if($y.SideIndicator -eq "<="){
     write-output "$($y.InputObject) Is present in the CSV but not in Music folder."
    }
 }
if($y.SideIndicator -eq "=="){
     write-output "All files present."
    }
```

Returns:

```
_____FOLDER_____

9913SA_File1.wav
9914SA_File2.wav
9915SA_File3.wav
9916SA_File4.wav
9917SA_File5.wav

_____CSV_____

9913SA_File1.wav
9914SA_File2.wav
9915SA_File3.wav
9916SA_File4.wav

_____COMPARE_____


InputObject                                                         SideIndicator                                                     
-----------                                                         -------------                                                     
9913SA_File1.wav                                                    ==                                                                
9914SA_File2.wav                                                    ==                                                                
9915SA_File3.wav                                                    ==                                                                
9916SA_File4.wav                                                    ==                                                                
9917SA_File5.wav                                                    =>                                                                

_____Formatted Results____

9917SA_File5.wav Is present in the Music folder but not in the CSV.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a csv file with the following:

```
ID  Audio File Path
1   99\13\SA_File1.docx
2   99\13\SA_File2.docx
3   99\13\SA_File3.docx
5   99\13\SA_File5.docx
```

Note: I removed `99\13\SA_File4.docx` from the list.

I then ran the following script:

```
$myCSV = Import-Csv -Path '/Users/me/myFiles.csv' | % {$_.'Audio File Path' -replace "\\", ""}
$myFolder = Get-ChildItem '/Users/me/test'

$compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $myCSV -DifferenceObject $myFolder

foreach($y in $compare){
    if($y.SideIndicator -eq "=>"){
     write-output "$($y.InputObject) Is present in the Music folder but not in CSV."
    }
    if($y.SideIndicator -eq "<="){
     write-output "$($y.InputObject) Is present in the CSV but not in the Music folder."
    }
 }
```

I have tested with removing a file from the folder and including that file in the CSV, and the script complies.

You do not need the `-passthru` flag when comparing object, and `Get-ChildItem` is good for this application.

---

**EDIT:**

Your results are rather strange, please see the script below (I've updated the file names to look more like yours):

```
$myFolder = Get-ChildItem '/Users/me/test'
$myCSV = Import-Csv -Path '/Users/me/myFiles.csv' | % {$_.'Audio File Path' -replace "\\", ""}
$compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $myCSV -DifferenceObject $myFolder

Write-Output "`n_____FOLDER_____`n"
$myFolder.Name

Write-Output "`n_____CSV_____`n"
$myCSV

Write-Output "`n_____COMPARE_____`n"
$compare

Write-Output "`n_____Formatted Results____`n"
foreach($y in $compare){
    if($y.SideIndicator -eq "=>"){
     write-output "$($y.InputObject) Is present in the Music folder but not in the CSV."
    }
    if($y.SideIndicator -eq "<="){
     write-output "$($y.InputObject) Is present in the CSV but not in Music folder."
    }
 }
```

This gives me the following output:

[Output from script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpShR.png)
Can you please run the script above and send the output?

Comment: This is close but it's outputting all the files and saying they're missing when they aren't (see edited post). How do I get the script to output just the missing files?

Comment: I've editted my post, please run the script and let's take a look at the output.

Comment: Turns out there was a hidden space in my CSV so it's working now. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome - might be worth running a trim() on your CSV columns to be safe :)